# Finding an element

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python Selenium package and there is this element that I want to access but there is no `id` to it. I tried doing it by:

```
find_element_by_class()
```

But it shows:

```
elem6=driver.find_element_by_class("ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'
```

**Here's the element that I want to access**

```html
<div aria-label="Delete" data-tooltip="Delete" style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="T-I J-J5-Ji nX T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs  ar7" act="10" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="asa"><div class="ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would'nt it be find_element_by_class_name('ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji') ?

Comment: Did you find element after changing `.find_element_by_class("ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji")` to `.find_element_by_class_name('ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji')`??? or not..because selenium does not support to `find_element_by_class` by passing compound class..

Comment: Yes . It shows compound class names not permitted

Answer (score 5):

You are using incorrect method name. It should be `find_element_by_class_name`.

You can see it in the error message that you are getting:

`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'`

Comment: InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted.
This is the error I get

Comment: @AAA Is this another issue from the one you described in your question? If so, please ask in a separate question.